# How do I convert a document made in Jsoup (the Java html parser) into a string

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup, html-parser

I have a document that was made in jsoup that looks like this

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
```

How do i convert that `doc` into a string.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
String htmlString = doc.toString();
```

As *Document* extends *Element* it also has got the method *html()* which "Retrieves the element's inner HTML" according to the [API](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/). So that should work:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
String htmlString = doc.html();
```

**Additional Info:**

Each *Document* object has got a reference to an instance of the inner class *Document.OutputSettings* which can be accessed via the method *outputSettings()* of Document. There you can enable/disable pretty-printing by using the setter *prettyPrint(true/false)*. See the API for *Document* and *Document.OutputSettings* for furtherinformation

Comment: The first code block gave me `[Ljava.lang.String;@383534aa` instead of the html / content. BTW what if it's a `Document[]`?

Answer (score 9):

`doc.toString()` works, as does `doc.outerHtml()`.

Comment: `Document.toString()` internally calls `outerHtml()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();     
 Elements post = doc.select("div.post-content");
 String dd = post.toString();
 Document ddd = Jsoup.parse(dd);
```

After parsing the string to document then you can use on it document functions

```
 Elements scriptTag = ddd.getElementsByTag("script");
 System.out.println(scriptTag);
```