# How can I convert a Jsoup Document[] array to a String[]?

Tags: java, arrays, jsoup

My question is the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865090/how-do-i-convert-a-document-made-in-jsoup-the-java-html-parser-into-a-string) except that instead of a single `Document` I have an array (`Document[]`).

I normally use R, not Java, so I apologize if it should be apparent how to change the solution from the linked thread for the case of an array.

The solution for the case of a single `Document` object was:

```
String htmlString = doc.html();
```

My code to create the object was:

```
Document[] target = new Document[20];
for(int n=0; n < strvec.length;n++){
    target[n] = Jsoup.connect(strvec[n]).get();
 }
```

I tried a few things like creating the original `target` object as `String[]`, putting `.toString()` on the end of `Jsoup.connect(strvec[n]).get()` and elsewhere, but these attempts were unsucessful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is assumed that serves is an array of String containing the URL to connect, you do not need to create another array of Document

```
String[] result = new String[strvec.length];
    for(int n=0; n < strvec.length;n++)
      result[n]=Jsoup.connect(strvec[n]).get().html();
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] htmlList = new String[target.length];
for(int i = 0; i < target.length; i++)
    htmlList[i] = target[i].html();
```

This loop should do what you want.

Comment: Thank you. It didn't give an error in the IDE when I pasted that in, but when I tried to run it it threw this error on the last line of that codeblock `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`